# No module named 'distutils.command.bdist_msi' when installing celery[sqs]

Tags: python, django, celery, amazon-ecs

I have Django app with celery task. I am switchI am trying to install celery[sqs] as written in [documentation](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/sqs.html) however I cannot because I am getting error during instalation. I want to use Amazon SQS on AWS in my Django app and I am not sure how to do it without celery[sqs] package installed.

I am using Windows.

I know that I can use Amazon MQ instead but I am running few task a day and SQS would be more than enough for me and less expensive.

Do you know how to fix this issue?

```
Collecting pycurl~=7.44.1
  Using cached pycurl-7.44.1.tar.gz (227 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qt57cr38\pycurl_3d30f8432e6a4a298adece529a63bace\setup.py", line 938, in <module>
          setup_args['cmdclass'] = {'bdist_msi': get_bdist_msi_version_hack()}
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qt57cr38\pycurl_3d30f8432e6a4a298adece529a63bace\setup.py", line 580, in get_bdist_msi_version_hack
          from distutils.command.bdist_msi import bdist_msi
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.command.bdist_msi'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```